# Getting java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed ERROR while trying multiple queries

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, forms

I'm trying to fetch data from database based on user input so the user can track orders. The file compiles fine in the IDE but throws this error in the browser:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

form.jsp

```
<form action="viewOrderHistory" method="Post" id="invoiceNumberLookup">
            Invoice Number:
            <BR><BR>
            <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="invoice_number">
            &nbsp;
            <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" value="View Order">
        </form>


            <form action="viewOrderHistory" method="Post" id="referenceNumberLookup">
            Reference Number:
            <BR><BR>
            <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="reference_number">
            &nbsp;
            <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" value="View Order">
        </form>
```

result.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Fetching Data From a Database</TITLE>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
        <H1>Fetching Data From a Database</H1>

        <% 
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost/app?user=root&password=password");

            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

            String first_name = request.getParameter("first_name");
            String last_name= request.getParameter("last_name");

            String invoice_number = request.getParameter("invoice_number");
            String reference_number = request.getParameter("reference_number");
            String amount = request.getParameter("amount");
            String status= request.getParameter("status");
            String date_created = request.getParameter("date_created");
            String quantity = request.getParameter("quantity");
            String product_name = request.getParameter("product_name");
            String product_price = request.getParameter("product_price");

            ResultSet resultset = 

                    statement.executeQuery("select * from customer where first_name = '" + first_name + "'") ;
            statement.executeQuery("select * from customer where last_name = '" + last_name + "'") ; 



                statement.executeQuery("select * from customer_order where amount = '" + amount + "'") ;
            statement.executeQuery("select * from customer_order where date_created = '" + date_created + "'") ; 

            statement.executeQuery("select * from customer_order where reference_number = '" + reference_number + "'") ; 
            statement.executeQuery("select * from customer_order where invoice_number = '" + invoice_number + "'") ; 
            statement.executeQuery("select * from customer_order where status = '" + status + "'") ; 
            statement.executeQuery("select * from ordered_product where quantity = '" + quantity + "'") ; 
statement.executeQuery("select * from ordered_product where product_name = '" + product_name + "'") ;
statement.executeQuery("select * from ordered_product where product_price = '" + product_price + "'") ;

            if(!resultset.next()) {
                out.println("Sorry, could not find that order. ");
            } else {
        %>

        <div class="banner">   
       <% 
           } 
       %>
            </div>

        Invoice Number: <%= resultset.getString("invoice_number") %>
        Reference Number: <%= resultset.getString("reference_number") %>
        Created by: <%= resultset.getString("first_name") %> <%= resultset.getString("last_name") %>
        Date Created: <%= resultset.getString("date_created") %>
        Grand Total: <%= resultset.getString("amount") %>


        Order:
        <TABLE BORDER="1">
            <TR>
               <TH>Product Name</TH>
               <TH>Product Price</TH>
               <TH>Quantity</TH>
           </TR>
           <TR>
               <TD> <%= resultset.getString("product_name") %> </TD>
               <TD> <%= resultset.getString("product_price") %> </TD>
               <TD> <%= resultset.getString("quantity") %> </TD>
           </TR>
       </TABLE>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Bee free to approve any answer that helped you. :)

Comment: @Aleksandar: The answers helped me understand the importance of watching for misplaced brackets and that I can not execute more than one query per statement. I appreciate those answers but it does not tell me how to execute multiple queries and print them on the page... This is what Im trying to do `:)`

Comment: Then edit the question. The question was about the exception, not about multiple queries. :)

Comment: @Aleksandar: I edited the question, do you mind editing your answer and I'll give you more reputation `;)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works (implying you are using a servlet):

Form.jsp

```
 <form method="post" action="viewPublishers">
            Please enter the publisher ID you wish to view:
            <BR><br>
            <input type='text' name='pub_id' required>
            <BR><BR>
            <input type='submit' value="View">

        </form>
```

Response.jsp

```
    <% 
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/app?user=root&password=12345");

                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

                String pub_id = request.getParameter("pub_id);  

                ResultSet resultset = 
                    statement.executeQuery("select * from publishers where id = '" + pub_id+ "'") ; 

                if(!resultset.next()) {
                    out.println("Sorry, could not find that publisher.Please enter a valid ID. <a href='viewPublishers'>Try Again.</a> ");
                } else {
            %>




  <table>
              <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Publisher ID</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Books</th>
</thead>


<tbody style="font-size:small;">
  <tr>
    <td data-label="Publiser ID"><%= resultset.getString("pub_id") %></td>
    <td data-label="First Name"><%= resultset.getString("first_name") %></td>
    <td data-label="Last Name"><%= resultset.getString("last_name") %></td>
    <td data-label="Books"><%= resultset.getString("books") %>

 </tr>
                </tbody>
</table>

<div>   <% 
           } 
       %></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After the part with

```
if(!resultset.next()) {
            out.println("Sorry, could not find that order. ");
        } else {
    %>

    <div class="banner">   
   <% 
       }
```

you are out from ResultSet. The last **}** is misplaced. Needs to go after closing table.

**EDIT**

Maybe not the best way, but it will work. Introduce more ResultSets for each statement and query. Then use them where you need them.

Example:

```
Statement s1 = connection.createStatement();
Statement s2 = connection.createStatement();
Statement s3 = connection.createStatement();
Statement s4 = connection.createStatement();
...
ResultSet rs1 = s1.exequteQuery(.....);
ResultSet rs2 = s2.exequteQuery(.....);
ResultSet rs3 = s3.exequteQuery(.....);
.......
```

and then use rs1 .... rsN where you need them. Working solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Note the [`Statement` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) says:

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time.

Now, you have these statements in your program:

```
ResultSet resultset = 

        statement.executeQuery("select * from customer where first_name = '" + first_name + "'") ;
        statement.executeQuery("select * from customer where last_name = '" + last_name + "'") ; 

        statement.executeQuery("select * from customer_order where amount = '" + amount + "'") ;
        statement.executeQuery("select * from customer_order where date_created = '" + date_created + "'") ; 

        statement.executeQuery("select * from customer_order where reference_number = '" + reference_number + "'") ; 
        statement.executeQuery("select * from customer_order where invoice_number = '" + invoice_number + "'") ; 
        statement.executeQuery("select * from customer_order where status = '" + status + "'") ; 
        statement.executeQuery("select * from ordered_product where quantity = '" + quantity + "'") ; 
        statement.executeQuery("select * from ordered_product where product_name = '" + product_name + "'") ;
        statement.executeQuery("select * from ordered_product where product_price = '" + product_price + "'") ;
```

This means you are calling the `executeQuery` several times with the same `Statement` object. But you are only saving the result of the first execution into `resultset`.

That is, the `ResultSet` object that `resultset` refers to is the one from this statement:

```
statement.executeQuery("select * from customer where first_name = '" + first_name + "'") ;
```

All the others that follow it are separate queries and are not stored in the same variable if that's what you thought you were doing. They just create the `ResultSet` object, and then it gets thrown away because you don't assign the result to any variable.

As soon as you call the second `executeQuery`, because only one `ResultSet` object is allowed, the `ResultSet` object stored in `resultset` is closed, and a new one is opened. Then another, and then another.

Anyway, after you go through all these statements, you get to the part where you check `resultset.next()`. But at this point, that object, as I said, has already been closed.

Basically, you should decide which of the queries you want to run, run only *that particular query*, and then you'll have a live, open `ResultSet` in `resultset`. And then you can fill it in.

---

In addition, the part that prints the values from the result set should be inside the `else` block. You placed them after the curly brace of that `else`, which means you'll have trouble when no rows are returned from the query, because you'll be trying to print them anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I took knowledge of the documentation which is a bit gibberish to me... What if I need to execute all the statements?

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do , but you can run one and fill all the data in the HTML, then the next, then the next and so on.

Comment: I'm trying to run multiple queries and have the data printed based on input. User enters his reference number in a form and click submit. The reference number is associated to an invoice stored in database which contains information about the order that the user can see on a page.

Comment: Well, if they have entered a reference number, you should query for reference number, and only for that. You can't do all the queries together and it's not efficient, either. You query by whatever the user passes, and you fill in the data from that query and that query only.

Comment: I understand what you mean but i'm visual... I understand better with examples... Would you mind updating your answer?

Comment: As I said, I'm not sure what it is that you are trying to achieve, really, because I am not familiar with your tables and your data and how you want to show it, and I can't understand why you have so many queries and what you intended to do with them. I don't think I can help you further beyond pointing out the mistake.

Comment: Are you saying that If I want to retrieve and display data from 3 different tables I have to create 3 different scripts?

Comment: No, I'm saying that you have to figure out by the user's input which query to run, and run it.